# Using arcpy.selectlayerbyattribute_management, getparameter?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, parameters

I am very new to scripting with ArcMap and I have been doing fairly well with google and youtube... but I've reached a problem.

I am trying to run a script in which country(ies) I specify from a feature are selected and zoomed to. this is so I can preset a template to begin a map composition with automating the first bits.

what works in python is this;

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Country_FeatureLayer", "NEW_SELECTION", " NAME = 'Country' ")
df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
```

Where I run into a problem is to make it into a tool script and add the "arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)" within the script, I don't think I am doing it right.  I've tried;

```
Country = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) # earlier in the script
NAME = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) # within the selectlayer line...
```

I'm sure this gets into the lack of education in scripting for me, which is something I am rectifying, anyone got any help for me?

Comment: I have attempted to correct this problem with many different "fixes" that I have found online. Overall the code works up until I add the parameter, that's when it fails to run. So I think it is a problem when I add the GetParameterAsText.

Answer (score 2):

When you are stuck with ArcPy and wanting to understand it well I recommend consulting its documentation.

The help page entitled [Setting script tool parameters](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/creating-tools/setting-script-tool-parameters.htm) leads to an equally valuable [Understanding script tool parameters](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/creating-tools/understanding-script-tool-parameters.htm).

I think you should start by addressing this code:

```
Country = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) # earlier in the script
NAME = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) # within the selectlayer line
```

Here you are trying to set the variable `Country` to whatever is returned to the script by the first parameter on your tool dialog (the one with index 0).

You are then trying to set another variable named `NAME` to the same thing i.e. whatever is returned to the script by the first parameter on your tool dialog.

I suspect that this code would work better if you used:

```
Country = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) # earlier in the script
NAME = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) # within the selectlayer line
```

so that the variable `Country` is set to whatever is returned to the script by the first parameter on your tool dialog (the one with index 0), and the other variable named `NAME` gets set to whatever is returned to the script by the second parameter on your tool dialog (the one with index 1).

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. These are not 2 different lines of code, They were 2 different attempts at fixing the problem (not within the same code)

Comment: Perhaps review these [tips on writing code snippets](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers) to present here.